# Facebook ads deferred deep linking not working on Instagram but same ad working fine on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, deep-linking, facebook-ads-api

I have created a Facebook Ad campaign with a deferred deep link which is placed on FB & Instagram. Now when the user already having my application in the device then they are going to mentioned deferred deep link & it's working completely fine on both the platform(Facebook & Instagram). But when the user doesn't have the application they should go on mentioned deferred link after installation, but in this case when users are clicking on my Facebook Ad they are going to mentioned deferred deep link after installation, but when users are clicking on Instagram Ad, they are not going to mentioned deferred deep link after installation.

Here is AndroidManifest.xml for deep link activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <tools:validation testUrl="https://www.everytech.com/user-profile" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.everytech.com" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.everytech.com" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="app"
                android:host="everytech.com" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Java Code in Activity to get a deferred link

```
private void handleDeferredLink(){
    AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this,
            appLinkData -> {
                if (null != appLinkData && null != appLinkData.getTargetUri())
                    parseDeepLink(appLinkData.getTargetUri());
                else openDefaultActivity();
            }
    );
}
```